# What does the German translate to in Philip K. Dick's "A Scanner Darkly"?

Tags: translation, philip-k-dick, language-explanation, a-scanner-darkly

When the main character Bob Arctor starts doubting himself after he writes a bad check to a locksmith. Arctor thought that his roommate wrote the check as a scam, but Arctor realized the handrwriting was too good. What was the German language of Arctor's inner dialogue?

Comment: Can you paste a quote as it appeared in the novel?

Comment: Ihr Instrumente freilich spottet mein,
Mit Rad und Kämmen, Walz und Bügel:
Ich stand am Tor, ihr solltet Schlüssel sein;
Zwar euer Bart ist kraus, doch hebt ihr nicht die Riegel.

Comment: Was grinsest du mir, hohler Schädel, her?
Als daß dein Hirn, wie meines, einst verwirret
Den leichten Tag gesucht und in der Dämmrung schwer,
Mit Luft nach Wahrheit, jämmerlich geirret.

Comment: Duplicate of [In the novel A Scanner Darkly what did the verses in German mean?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/59071/in-the-novel-a-scanner-darkly-what-did-the-verses-in-german-mean)